# Opacity of image in IB is not correct

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, photoshop

semi-transparent images that I added to my resources. When viewed in interface builder it doesn't show as transparent as it did when I had it in Photoshop. I made sure that the opacity was the way I wanted it and the background was transparent pixels. I even tried saving the image as PNG-24 preset and checked the transparency box in PS mobile and web. And in interface builder I made sure that the opaque box in view attributes was unchecked. But after all this the image doesn't display with the proper opacity as I set it as.

Comment: What about when you compile and run the app on the phone? IB is just a layout thing - it doesn't actually show what your app will. Sometimes controls are off by a few pixels etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save it as PNG-32, 24 Bits (3*8) is just RGB, so it doesn't have an alpha channel.

Comment: I don't have the PNG-32 option in PS.

Comment: Seems it's not called that way in Photoshop. If you're using the "save for web" dialog, make sure to check the transparency box. Using the normal "save as...", alpha should be included by default when you select PNG.